# What are some examples of image effects (css)

Tags: css

I am wondering what image effects can be done via css, such as the glint from Minecraft. Is there any way to do this, or similar, effects?

Comment: This question is off topic for this site, and it's very easy to find some examples of what can be done with CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter springs to mind...

Answer (score 0):

Try this script in CSS: http://una.im/CSSgram/

You can replicate the Instagram's filter with only a class!